# How to display text written to an external text file on Java?

Tags: java

I was wondering because I made my program save data to an external program, but I need to know how to display on Java.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoringInfo {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
                Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("\n Enter the customer's name: "); 
                String name1=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("\n Enter the customer's first part of the    address: ");
        String Address=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("\n Enter the rest of the address:");
        String Address2=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("\n Enter the customer's E-mail: ");
        String Email=keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Customer has been added to the list.");
        File file = new File("CustomerData.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(writer); 
        output.println(name1);
        output.println(Address);
        output.println(Address2);
        output.println(Email);
```

I was wondering if you use something like BufferedReader or another code?
    output.close();

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Scanner` to read from files too.

```
File file = new File("CustomerData.txt");
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
```

And you can apply the knowledge you know about `Scanner`s to this.

Alternatively you could use a `BufferedReader` (which is faster).

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CustomerData.txt"));
```

And use:

```
reader.readLine();
```

To read the next line.